# Generate payment URL in custom email

Tags: actions, woocommerce-offtopic

When a particular order status is triggered, a custom email is sent to the shopper. I would like to include a link in the email for them to pay for the order.

From my current understanding, the payment URL should look something like:

```
http://www.example.com/checkout/order-pay/[order number here]
```

Here is my function which sends the email and generates the payment URL:

```
add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed", "my_notification");

function my_notification($order_id) {
   global $woocommerce;
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   if($order->status === 'prop' ) {
      //HERE IS THE ISSUE
      $payment_page = get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'pay' ) ) . '/order-pay/' . $order->get_order_number();

      // Create a mailer
      $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();

      $message_body = __( 'My message to the shopper with payment <a href="'.$payment_page.'">link</a>' );

      $message = $mailer->wrap_message(
      // Message head and message body.
      sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message_body );

      // Send email
      $mailer->send( $order->billing_email, sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message );

      // Set status to pending payment
      $order->update_status('pending');
     }
}
```

The above generates the URL as I expect it to, however when browsing to the generated URL, I get the Woocommerce error:

> Sorry, this order is invalid and cannot be paid for.

I have also tried:

```
$checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
```

Which ends up with a fatal error when the order status is triggered:

> Call to a member function get_checkout_url() on a non-object in ... functions.php on line ...

How would I generate a **valid** payment URL for an order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct method for generating a payment URL is:

[`get_checkout_payment_url()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_checkout_payment_url)

So my code changed to to:

```
$payment_page = $order->get_checkout_payment_url();
```

Which generates the following URL:

```
http://www.example.co.za/checkout/order-pay/[order-number]?pay_for_order=true&key=order_[order-key]
```

Which is what I was looking for.

**Note that the order status must be set to unpaid or pending in order for the generated link to be valid**